# If a paper has co-first authors, is the next author after the first authors considered the second author?

Tags: authorship

I've already read this question in this arena, but I couldn't find an answer.

The question is: if someone obtains first co-authorship, does the "third" author gain "second authorship"?

Comment: What is the  significance of "second authorship"? In my field (which is one where author order matters), the only meaningful positions are "first author, " "last author," and "middle author" (middle=not first and not last.)

Comment: In the policy of our Institute, a Cancer Comprehensive Center in Italy, and in the Ministry of Health'policy as well, the meaningful positions are: first, second, last and corresponding author

Comment: If second author has a different weight in your institution, then you should be asking them for advice. Also, by no definition third does equal second.

Answer (score 3):

In this case, first authorship is being used for some sort of competitive ranking.  As such, if there are two first authors, then in the [typical custom of competitive ranking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ranking#Strategies_for_assigning_rankings) there is no second author: the next author is the third author.

If this is being defined and used for a specific purpose by a specific institution, however, it is possible that institution has its own interpretation of rankings, which can only be determined by consulting the appropriate people or documentation at that institution.